# Computing $(a+b)^*c^*(a+b)^* \cap (b+c)^*a^*(b+c)^*$

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, automata, regular-expressions

how can I find the regular expression for this intersection  ?
I've tried to find words but it did not help too much..

$$[\; (a+b)^* c^* (a+b)^* \;] \cap [\; (c+b)^* a^* (c+b)^*\;]$$

Comment: A mechanical way is to construct a DFA $D_1$ (resp. $D_2$) for the first (resp. second) expression, intersect them (by taking the Cartesian product of their states) and then convert the resulting DFA $D_1 \cap D_2$ back to a regular expression.

Comment: What is the meaning of the expression $(a+b)^* c^* (a+b)^*$?

Answer (score 1):

Any word can be written as a concatenation of *runs*. For example,
$$ aaabbabaccbbbc = a^3b^2a^1b^1a^1c^2b^3c^1. $$
Each run is a positive power of a symbol, and the constraint is that two adjacent runs are powers of different symbols. Each word can be decomposed into runs in a unique way.

The regular expression $(a+b)^*c^*(a+b)^*$ captures all words with at most one $c$-run. Similarly, the regular expression $(b+c)^*a^*(b+c)^*$ captures all words with at most one $a$-run. Therefore the intersection consists of all words with at most one $c$-run and at most one $a$-run.

Since the only other possible run is a $b$-run, we get that the intersection is
$$
b^*a^*b^*c^*b^* + b^*c^*b^*a^*b^*.
$$